# ListView ClickListener for Dialog subitem

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a dialog with a ListView.There are two textviews in listview item.I want to get the texts in both the textviews on listview's click listener.Is it possible?I tried the below code snippet but it gives the first textview item only.I want to dismiss the dialog on clicking on any listview item also.

Code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        Object item = lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        changeIngredient.dismiss();

                        ParameterName.setText(item.toString());


                    }
                });
```

This is my adapter class:

```
public class CustomListAdapterDialog extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] Name;
private final Double[] Price;
private final Typeface tf,tfb;
Dialog changeIngredient;

public CustomListAdapterDialog(Activity context, String[] NameArray,Double[] PriceArray, Typeface tf, Typeface tfb, Dialog changeIngredient) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.dialog_listitem,NameArray);

    this.context=context;
    this.Name=NameArray;
    this.Price=PriceArray;
    this.tf=tf;
    this.tfb=tfb;
    this.changeIngredient=changeIngredient;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_listitem, null,true);


    final TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_IngredientName);
    final TextView txtPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_IngredientPrice);


    txtName.setText(Name[position]);
    txtName.setTypeface(tf);
    txtPrice.setTypeface(tf);
    String priceValue = String.valueOf(Price[position]);
    txtPrice.setText("$"+priceValue);

    /*txtName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, txtName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, txtPrice.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            changeIngredient.dismiss();
        }
    });
*/
    return rowView;

};
```

}

Comment: Can you show the adapter and your data object? You'll probably have to cast item to your data object, which should hold all data including the texts.

Comment: I tried to assign click to both items in adapter class.Its working.But i need to get this in listview's clicklistener itself because i want to get the item selected by the user.

Comment: I know, so show your adapter and your data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `view` second parameter of `onItemClick` method for accessing both TextView values as:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {
            TextView txtViewOne = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_one);
            TextView txtViewTwo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_two);
            String strTxtOne=txtViewOne.getText().toString();
         }});
```